# find row with element in big matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

I have

```
result=
   [1   0   0
    2   0   0
    3   0   0
    1   2   0
    1   3   0
    2   3   0
    1   2   3
    4   0   0
    5   0   0
    6   0   0
    4   5   0
    4   6   0
    5   6   0
    4   5   6
    7   0   0
    8   0   0
    9   0   0
    7   8   0
    7   9   0
    8   9   0
    7   8   9]
```

I want find for example 1.
I wrote this code:

```
[o,p]=find(result==1)
 for i=1 : numel(o)
 member(i,:)=result(o(i),:)
 end
```

after run it shows

```
member=[1     0     0
        1     2     0
        1     3     0
        1     2     3]
```

and it's correct.
My question is when my matrix is bigger, for example this matrix

```
result =
[0.142  0   0   0   0
0.2635  0   0   0   0
0.2589  0   0   0   0
0.2259  0   0   0   0
0.1096  0   0   0   0
0.142   0.2635  0   0   0
0.142   0.2589  0   0   0
0.142   0.2259  0   0   0
0.142   0.1096  0   0   0
0.2635  0.2589  0   0   0
0.2635  0.2259  0   0   0
0.2635  0.1096  0   0   0
0.2589  0.2259  0   0   0
0.2589  0.1096  0   0   0
0.2259  0.1096  0   0   0
0.142   0.2635  0.2589  0   0
0.142   0.2635  0.2259  0   0
0.142   0.2635  0.1096  0   0
0.142   0.2589  0.2259  0   0
0.142   0.2589  0.1096  0   0
0.142   0.2259  0.1096  0   0
0.2635  0.2589  0.2259  0   0
0.2635  0.2589  0.1096  0   0
0.2635  0.2259  0.1096  0   0
0.2589  0.2259  0.1096  0   0
0.142   0.2635  0.2589  0.2259  0
0.142   0.2635  0.2589  0.1096  0
0.142   0.2635  0.2259  0.1096  0
0.142   0.2589  0.2259  0.1096  0
0.2635  0.2589  0.2259  0.1096  0
0.142   0.2635  0.2589  0.2259  0.1096
0.1638  0   0   0   0
0.223   0   0   0   0
0.3345  0   0   0   0
0.0637  0   0   0   0
0.215   0   0   0   0
0.1638  0.223   0   0   0
0.1638  0.3345  0   0   0
0.1638  0.0637  0   0   0
0.1638  0.215   0   0   0
0.223   0.3345  0   0   0
0.223   0.0637  0   0   0
0.223   0.215   0   0   0
0.3345  0.0637  0   0   0
0.3345  0.215   0   0   0
0.0637  0.215   0   0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.0637  0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.215   0   0
0.1638  0.3345  0.0637  0   0
0.1638  0.3345  0.215   0   0
0.1638  0.0637  0.215   0   0
0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0   0
0.223   0.3345  0.215   0   0
0.223   0.0637  0.215   0   0
0.3345  0.0637  0.215   0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0.215   0
0.1638  0.223   0.0637  0.215   0
0.1638  0.3345  0.0637  0.215   0
0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0.215   0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0.215
0.1772  0   0   0   0
0.2412  0   0   0   0
0.2585  0   0   0   0
0.2068  0   0   0   0
0.1163  0   0   0   0
0.1772  0.2412  0   0   0
0.1772  0.2585  0   0   0
0.1772  0.2068  0   0   0
0.1772  0.1163  0   0   0
0.2412  0.2585  0   0   0
0.2412  0.2068  0   0   0
0.2412  0.1163  0   0   0
0.2585  0.2068  0   0   0
0.2585  0.1163  0   0   0
0.2068  0.1163  0   0   0
0.1772  0.2412  0.2585  0   0
0.1772  0.2412  0.2068  0   0
0.1772  0.2412  0.1163  0   0
0.1772  0.2585  0.2068  0   0
0.1772  0.2585  0.1163  0   0
0.1772  0.2068  0.1163  0   0
0.2412  0.2585  0.2068  0   0
0.2412  0.2585  0.1163  0   0
0.2412  0.2068  0.1163  0   0
0.2585  0.2068  0.1163  0   0
0.1772  0.2412  0.2585  0.2068  0
0.1772  0.2412  0.2585  0.1163  0
0.1772  0.2412  0.2068  0.1163  0
0.1772  0.2585  0.2068  0.1163  0
0.2412  0.2585  0.2068  0.1163  0
0.1772  0.2412  0.2585  0.2068  0.1163
0.1221  0   0   0   0
0.2792  0   0   0   0
0.2557  0   0   0   0
0.2393  0   0   0   0
0.1037  0   0   0   0
0.1221  0.2792  0   0   0
0.1221  0.2557  0   0   0
0.1221  0.2393  0   0   0
0.1221  0.1037  0   0   0
0.2792  0.2557  0   0   0
0.2792  0.2393  0   0   0
0.2792  0.1037  0   0   0
0.2557  0.2393  0   0   0
0.2557  0.1037  0   0   0
0.2393  0.1037  0   0   0
0.1221  0.2792  0.2557  0   0
0.1221  0.2792  0.2393  0   0
0.1221  0.2792  0.1037  0   0
0.1221  0.2557  0.2393  0   0
0.1221  0.2557  0.1037  0   0
0.1221  0.2393  0.1037  0   0
0.2792  0.2557  0.2393  0   0
0.2792  0.2557  0.1037  0   0
0.2792  0.2393  0.1037  0   0
0.2557  0.2393  0.1037  0   0
0.1221  0.2792  0.2557  0.2393  0
0.1221  0.2792  0.2557  0.1037  0
0.1221  0.2792  0.2393  0.1037  0
0.1221  0.2557  0.2393  0.1037  0
0.2792  0.2557  0.2393  0.1037  0
0.1221  0.2792  0.2557  0.2393  0.1037
0.1638  0   0   0   0
0.223   0   0   0   0
0.3345  0   0   0   0
0.0637  0   0   0   0
0.215   0   0   0   0
0.1638  0.223   0   0   0
0.1638  0.3345  0   0   0
0.1638  0.0637  0   0   0
0.1638  0.215   0   0   0
0.223   0.3345  0   0   0
0.223   0.0637  0   0   0
0.223   0.215   0   0   0
0.3345  0.0637  0   0   0
0.3345  0.215   0   0   0
0.0637  0.215   0   0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.0637  0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.215   0   0
0.1638  0.3345  0.0637  0   0
0.1638  0.3345  0.215   0   0
0.1638  0.0637  0.215   0   0
0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0   0
0.223   0.3345  0.215   0   0
0.223   0.0637  0.215   0   0
0.3345  0.0637  0.215   0   0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0.215   0
0.1638  0.223   0.0637  0.215   0
0.1638  0.3345  0.0637  0.215   0
0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0.215   0
0.1638  0.223   0.3345  0.0637  0.215]
```

So when I search for 0.142 using that code it doesn't give an error but it gives the warning

> The variable appears to change size on every loop iteration. Consider preallocating for speed.

and answer returns `[]`, meaning it can't find 0.142. So what is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: Might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab?s=1|3.4299

Comment: I haven't read your question.. but I don't think that's what a minimal example should look like...

Comment: The reason your code does not find any values is not because of the size of the matrix, but that the values stored in the matrix are not equal to `0.142`, despite what MATLAB is showing you. Try `format long` and see what the values of `result` look like.

Comment: yes your right its solved
Thanks sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the warning to disapear you can put the following line above your for loop:

```
member = zeros(length(o),size(result,2));
```

This pre-allocates the size before you begin to assign to member matrix. Hence Matlab knows what the size is going to be.

Coming to your code it works perfectly fine. Consider also modifying the find function as follows:

```
[o,p]=find(result==0.142)
```

Comment: sorry I tried  and put the piece of code but the code doesn't  work it cant find for example 0.1420 and `member` variable is []

Comment: you know `find function`doesn't work

Comment: `[o,p]` is [] for biger matrix

Comment: Hi @mojtabadad I tried to run your code,and was able to get the desired result.
Are you trying to run the same code that  you have given in the question with the 0.142 case?

Comment: Thanks sir its solve

Comment: Oh thats great to hear,what did you change?